# search inside an arraylist

Tags: android, arrays

I've some `String Array` (like below) and I want to search inside it. I created an `editText` and a `Button`. What's best way to do this search?

```
a0[0]="one";
a0[1]="two";
[...]
a1[0]="one-zero";
a1[1]="one-one";
[...]
a2[0]="two-zero";
a2[1]="two-one";

EditText searchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchfield);
Button searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchbutton);
searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        for (String s : Facts_Array) {
            if (searchField.getText().toString().contains(s)) {
                [...]
```

Comment: Show the code where you initialize `Facts_Array`.

Comment: Hello, I don't have that code, I realize how write correct code. Thanks

Comment: So what's with the upmost 7 lines? In the piece of code you're showing `a0`, `a1` and `a2` but you don't seem to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"some string array" How long is it? If it isn't long, and you aren't experiencing performance issues you shouldn't use your time on this other than using linear search. This is premature optimization if you use your time on this. 
Binary Search is another option but as I said above, only consider optimization if you have performance issues

Comment: Understood. Same strings (200) are very long (like 500 chars or more than). What do you advice?

Comment: 200 is very long to human, but not to computer. Are you experiencing lag issues? My advice is, try out what you can do to get it working. If you have problems with that, you can ask again on how to optimize it.

Comment: No lag (for now). They're the tales inside a scrollview. thanks.